# Skill checks, can they go negative?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills

Example: Attempting to snipe with no perks means I get a -20 to my stealth check. When I roll the d20, can the result be negative, or is 0 the absolute minimum?

Comment: Did I miss something? DC (Difficulty Class) starts at some value (example DC 15), it can then get more difficult by adding more (+5, eg DC 20), or it can get easier by attributes, feats, etc (-5, eg DC 10). A DC -20 would to me indicate a auto success (with the exception of rolling a natural 1). I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: @DoStuffZ he meant the check, not the DC

Comment: Ahh, so a bucketload of unfavorable situations, uphill, sun, wind, bad attribs, what have you. 1d20-20 to make a DC 15 check. Hehe tough luck :D

Comment: Just out of couriosity would it matter? If it was 0 or minus -20 you would still not pass the check.

Comment: Isn't a natural 1 still a possible success for a skill check?

Comment: @bennyboy Some skill checks are DC 0, but still present, like climbing a knotted rope along a wall.

Comment: @Erik yes. DoStuffZ is wrong on this part. Nat20/Nat1 only applies to attack rolls and saving throws.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Skill checks are pass/fail, with occasional house rules for natural 20 or 1. If your check fails to beat the DC, it doesn't matter if you got 0 or -900.

Comment: @JustinMorgan: There are several skills where the amount you fail by has an effect in 3.5, did they drop that from pathfinder?  UMD with an unknown magic item for instance, if you fail by 10 or more an explosion occurs.

Comment: @MooingDuck - I didn't think about that. Good point.

Answer (score 18):

#### It goes negative

This is a case of "the rules don't say otherwise". In particular, the [Skills](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills#TOC-Skill-Checks) section has nothing to say about results being "low-capped" at 0.

> Skills can be further modified by a wide variety of sources—by your race, by a class ability, by equipment, by spell effects or magic items, and so on. [...]
>
> If the result of your skill check is equal to or greater than the difficulty class (or DC) of the task you are attempting to accomplish, you succeed. If it is less than the DC, you fail. Some tasks have varying levels of success and failure depending on how much your check is above or below the required DC. Some skill checks are opposed by the target's skill check. When making an opposed skill check, the attempt is successful if your check result exceeds the result of the target.

I would expect the rule to be found somewhere in this paragraph, but there's nothing.

Do note that some skills have DC 0 examples, like [Climb](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/climb)

> DC 0: A slope too steep to walk up, or a knotted rope with a wall to brace against.

This DC could never be failed without negative check results, e.g. due to low Strength, or the -5 penalty for accelerated climbing.

Comment: DC can even go negative. A -5 DC can be passed every time except by someone working with significant impediments. Walking across a parking lot without a scooter might be DC -10, to use an IRL example. If you're disabled or carrying something bulky, it becomes an issue.

Comment: "Low capped" is a cute synonym for "floored." :)

Comment: Also note that tracking how far negative you go is important for opposed checks.  I once passed a Move Silently check (it was 3.5, po-tay-to...) with a -2.

Comment: @Lexible I knew there was a real word for that...